# Selenium ChromeDriver will consistently fail to load web resources such as Bootstrap, JQuery, etc

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It's all in the title. I will start chrome driver with the code that I have below, and it will only load up the resources such as JQuery, Bootstrap, and others. It will take an exceptionally long time to load the page as well when this happens. I'll get errors saying that the resource failed to load due to them timing out.

I'm pretty ignorant on what I need to do, so any documentation that someone is willing to throw my way which helped them find the solution, or ever something that is similar will be greatly appreciated. Here's what I've tried:
1) disabling the proxy settings using the ChromeOptions object
2) Disabling SSL certificates
3) Disabling AVG
4) Disabling firewall
5) Internet connection is fine in my room

Another thing that I tried doing was looking at the log file with `ChromeOptions.SetLogginPreference(string, logLevel)`, which worked in ChromeDriver75 but it no longer works in ChromeDriver76. The same code for looking at logs doesn't work the same across drivers.

```
//SETTING UP THE DRIVER WITH SOME OPTIONS
public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
{
    IWebDriver iwd;
    ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions(){Proxy = null};
    co.AddAdditionalCapability("ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS", true, true);
    co.AddAdditionalCapability("ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS", true, true);
    co.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors", "--ignore-ssl-errors");
    co.SetLoggingPreference("all", logLevel: LogLevel.All);
    iwd = new ChromeDriver("path/to/driver", co);
}

//ME TRYING TO LOAD THE SITE 10 TIMES
public bool TryLoad()
{   
    //bool for if it was completed or not
    bool b = false;


    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Gen.Write("\r\nLoading New Page==>", false, ConsoleColor.Cyan);
            p.iwd_Driver.GoTo(p.sURL);
            if (WasEverythingWasLoaded(p))
            {
                Gen.Write(" (/) Page Done!", true, ConsoleColor.Green);
                b = true;
                return b;
            }
            Gen.Write($"{(i == 0 ? "Failed to load resources" : $"Failed to load resources {i + 1} times")}.", false, ConsoleColor.Red);
        }
        catch (WebDriverException e)
        {
            Gen.Write($"\r\n\r\nFATAL::Failed to load the page {p.sURL}\r\nException info: {e}\r\n\r\n", true, ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.White);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!b)
                Gen.Write($"\r\nAttempting again==>", true, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
        }
    try
    {
        Gen.Write("\r\nLoading New Page==>", false, ConsoleColor.Cyan);
        p.iwd_Driver.GoTo(p.sURL);
        if (WasEverythingWasLoaded(p))
        {
            Gen.Write(" (/) Page Done!", true, ConsoleColor.Green);
            b = true;
            return b;
        }
    }
    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
        Gen.Write($"Something is very wrong and needs to be acknowledged here... try flushing the DNS, restarting VS, restarting computer," +
            $" canceling some services etc. because it isn't just Selenium that is being a problem here...\r\nException Info: {e}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Gen.Write($"\r\n\r\nFATAL::Exception when loading {p.sURL}\r\nException info: {e}\r\n\r\n", true, ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.DarkGray);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!b)
            p.iwd_Driver.Terminate();
    }
    return b;
}

//trying to interogate the log files. I want to check to see if everything was 
//successfully loaded. If not, then I'm going to try again. This works with
// chormedriver75 but not with chromedriver76 for some reason...
private static bool WasEverythingWasLoaded(Page p)
{
    ILogs v = p.iwd_Driver.Manage().Logs;

    IReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs;
    try
    {
        logs = p.iwd_Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        Gen.Write("Looks like I can't take logs with this version...", true, ConsoleColor.Blue, ConsoleColor.White);
        return true;
    }
    //spit out the logs
    foreach (LogEntry le in logs)
    Gen.Write($"LogEntry: {le.Message}", true, ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.White);

    //if the count of the relevant logs is greater than a certain amount, then fail it
    return logs.Where(x =>
            x.Level == LogLevel.Severe
            && x.Message.ToLower().Contains("failed to load resource")
            && !x.Message.Contains(@"https://wes.sandbook.ca/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)")
    ).ToList().Count() < 1;
}
```

Expecting:
I'm expecting my driver to simply open and go to the page that I ask it to consistently. I only sort of understand what those chrome options are doing, so let me know if it looks out of place.

Comment: Your issue is with loading resources? Do any resources work? Css, images, libraries. Have you tried making a test page to test loading resources from the internet?

Comment: There is the odd time where some of the external js or css gets loaded but it is rare. I've made a page that is a `<head>` wrapped in an `<html>`. The stuff in the head is every resource that I need. I've tried doing this so that I can get the resources cached. Those resources just fail to load just as often as it does when I try to load the entire target page.

Comment: It's starting to sound like it might be a firewall issue. It seems inconsistent so it's nearly impossible to say

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix. Super gimicky, but it works.

It definitely has to do with something getting slowed down and it times out. What I did is a took all of the resources that I need, created an HTML doc that contained nothing but

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="...the_guds..."></script> <!--could be for bootstrap, favicon, or whatever-->
    </head>
</html>
```

for each resource that I needed to include and I systematically load each one after initialising the driver. After that, the resource gets cached, and it makes loading it super fast after that.